# Passing data to an EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm a newbie learning MVC and your help would be much appreciated. I have two models, Firms and Address. I'm trying to have a simple form where someone can add Firm details.

When the Firm Form is loaded, an Editor template containing Address model is Rendered. The problem I'm having is a straight forward one. I've even seen solutions to it on stack overflow but in my case it wont work (strange). When I'm passing new `Innuendo.Models.AddressModel()` to the Address Template, during Postback the `ModelState.IsValid` is false and `Model.Address` is still set to null. What am I doing wrong?

**Firm View**

```
@model Innuendo.Models.FirmModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>FirmModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/EditorTemplates/_Address.cshtml", new Innuendo.Models.AddressModel())
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogoPath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogoPath)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogoPath)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Editor Template _Address**

```
@model Innuendo.Models.AddressModel
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Street)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Street)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Town)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Town)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Town)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.County)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County)
</div>
```

**Firm Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(FirmModel firmmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        firmmodel.FirmId = Guid.NewGuid();    
        db.Firms.Add(firmmodel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(firmmodel);
}
```

**Firms Model**

```
[Table("Firms")]
public class FirmModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FirmId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Firm Name")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual AddressModel Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string LogoPath { get; set; }
}
```

**Address Model**

```
[Table("Addresses")]
public class AddressModel
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "House Name/Number")]

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string HouseName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string County { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using editor template as a partial view therefor MVC generates wrong ids for `input`s and model binder fails to bind address's properties. To  workaround first rename your `_Address.cshtml` to `Address.cshtml` to match with type name. Second replace

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/EditorTemplates/_Address.cshtml", new Innuendo.Models.AddressModel())
```

with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Address)
```

Or if your view name dose not match with type name. You could explicitly set template name also:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Address,"_Address")
```

As you can see you don't need to write full path of your templates or view since MVC knows where to find them.

And if `AddressId` generates model state error, and you don't want use a view model without `AddressId` you could write a custom model binder to inject new GUID while binding.

```
public class AddressBinder:DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
            ((Address)bindingContext.Model).ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        else
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

And register your model binder in `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // other codes

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Address), new AddressBinder());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I tried this before. And it does work. My only problem is that ModelState.IsValid is false as it keeps on saying that AddressId is required. When you look at the FirmModel, AddressId is an empty Guid. I tried updating the AddressId during postback and then called the tryUpdateModel, but ModelState.IsValid still remains false.

Comment: The only way I managed to make it work, if in the HttpGet I create an instance of the FirmModel and set the AddressId to a new Guid. Then I pass this new instance of the firmModel to the View. Then everything works as AddressID was already set. However Im wondering if this is the best way to do it, or if I can set a new Guid when calling the EditorFor method.

Comment: Creating new instance of your object in get method is better then in editor template. Also I suggested even better way in my updated post.

Comment: I've revisited what youre suggestion to override the AddressBinder. I must say the solution is not Good. Its Awesome. Its clean, efficient and makes sense. Tip o' Hat.